# Vue.js selected value in input does not match :selected parameter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Vue.js select after page load value what matches v-model but ignores :selected attribute.
Code:

```
<select class="form-control " :required="true"
    :class="{'is-invalid': errors.has('item_'+index) }"
    :name="'item_'+index"
    v-validate="'required'"
    v-model="item.text_value"
    v-if="item.type =='TYPE_TEXT' ">
        <option
        v-for="(itemz, index) in (getwords(item.product_parameter_value.text))"
        :value="itemz"
        v-bind:selected="index === 0"
        >{{ itemz }}</option>
    </select>
```

The item.text_value is single word (Option2 etc)
getwords(item.product_parameter_value.text) returns array - ['Option1'],['Option2'],['Option3'] etc.
So selected value always match item.text_value but not :selected.
Is there any way to set selected value to first item in array?

Comment: You would want to move the item to the top of the array for it to be at the top - but this really isn't ideal as it changes otherwise accepted normal functionality

Comment: please share live snippet?

Comment: You are not understand my problem.
In dropdown list it seems in right order. But vue always select element if they match the v-model value. But i need selected first value on array after page load, not the v-model value

Answer (score 0):

You should control this by setting the `v-model` to the correct value, instead of by trying to force the DOM to be out of synch with the data model.

Ideally this would be done by just setting `item.text_value` in the data block of the component; if the correct value can't be known ahead of time, you can read your `getwords` function before the component mounts to find the first element:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    item: {
      text_value: "" // ideally you would init the correct value here
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getwords() { // simplified stub for your data source:
      return ["Option1", "Option2", "Option3"]
    }
  },

  beforeMount() {
    // if you can't init it in the data block,
    // read the value from getwords() here instead:
    this.item.text_value = this.getwords()[0]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="item.text_value">
    <option v-for="itemz, index) in (getwords())" :value="itemz">{{itemz}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, i dont understand one thing before. Data in array must be identical with v-model. Vue.js is so strange thing sometimes.
Is there any good book for learning it?

Comment: It's just that the array represents the options, and the v-model represents the selected option; so yes for them to match up they have to be identical.   Vue takes a little different mindset than for example jQuery -- instead of working in the DOM you want to do most of your work in the data model and the component methods; the DOM is basically a side effect.

Comment: (I'm sorry, I don't know of a book to recommend.)